# Is it bad practice to use a static class as a variable container to pass among the entire program

Tags: c#, winforms, class

I really like to get some input on this approach. I have created a static class to hold variables that will be used through my application. Is this bad practice? I want to know more about this so in the future I don't make bad design structures.

Here is my static class:

```
 public static class clsIdStorage
{
    #region Pass Through Variable
    public static int? WorkOrderNumber { get; set; }
    public static bool WorkOrderVerified { get; set; }
    public static bool ProductSelected { get; set; }
    public static int EmployeeID { get; set; }
    public static bool CheckedIn { get; set; }
    public static int ProductSerialNumber { get; set; }
    public static int BoardSerialNumber { get; set; }
    public static long ProductID { get; set; }
    public static long BoardID { get; set; }
    public static string FullName {get; set;}
    public static int? BoardWoId { get; set; }
    public static int? ProductWoId { get; set; }
    public static bool ValidProductWOID { get; set; }
    public static bool ValidBoardWOID { get; set; }
    public static string PartNumber { get; set; }
    public static string BoardPartNumber { get; set; }
    public static object ProcessorBoard { get; set; }
    public static object AudioBoard { get; set; }
    public static bool RepairsCompleted { get; set; }
    public static int WorkOrderLookUp { get; set; }
    #endregion

    #region Time Variable
    // Work Order Time
    public static string EmployeeCheckIn { get; set; }
    public static string EmployeeCheckOut { get; set; }
    public static string BoardWorkOrderTime { get; set; }
    public static string ProductWorkOrderTime { get; set; }

    // Product Time
    public static string ProductCheckIn { get; set; }
    public static string ProductCheckOut { get; set; }

    // Board Time
    public static string BoardCheckIn { get; set; }
    public static string BoardCheckOut { get; set; }

    // Process flow variables
    public static int LocationID { get; set; }
    public static object PreviousLocation { get; set; }
    public static int ScenarioID { get; set; }
    #endregion
}
```

Comment: [CodeReview.SE](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) would be better for "best practices."

Comment: Instead of `static` class, Keep them in configuration files. Search for WinForm applicaiton resources.

Comment: @Evanark here is a link to [Static Classes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/79b3xss3.aspx)

Answer (score 4):

A problem I see with this approach is that your static class and members appear to be related to something that you need multiple instances of.

For example, when you set these values above, you will have one instance of each value (like ProductID) at a time. Some people choose an object oriented approach for storing multiple instances of ProductIDs etc. for this type of information.

I still use static classes a lot with calling functions, but when I need to store many instances or records of the same type of information, I choose an object oriented approach.

As far as being able to call a static class and read its variables among the entire program, this is fine and useful in ways. But the outline of your members makes me think the approach is wrong for that type of data.

Comment: Well, the program deals with one productID at a time, for example I am building repair check program log repair time for a given serial number(productID), each time a serial number is scanned, the productID the time is started and when the user clicks finished, the time stops. Then new serial number is scanned and the ID is overwritten. This program is only used by one person. I do see the value of designing it differently for multiple ID.  I originally created this class just to pass values back and forth instead of passing values from form to form. Its more of a container.

Answer (score 3):

The biggest problem here is related to dependencies. Every single project in your solution will need to have a reference to your static class. If you need to add even one new value then you need to recompile all of your classes.

Also, if you have a project that defines a custom class that you would like to reference in your static class then you have a cyclic dependency issue.

You are also exposing a lot of variables to all of your solution potentially allowing parts of the code to do unsafe things (i.e. overwriting file contents based on paths found in the static file.)

This is a bad practice.

You should use config files or some form of dependency injection instead.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: no, it's probably not good practice.
Long answer: the [Code Review stack exchange](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) is a much better place for this question. I suggest taking it there.